# Can someone recommend an Exif editor?

Tags: software-recommendation

Anyone knows a good exif editor for ubuntu? I need some simple functions like importing and exporting exif infos from a picture, copying exif info from one picture to another.

I'd prefer a gtk+ application, better if stand alone and not a function integrated in photo manager.

Comment: @skalka: i use GIMP and never lose EXIF info in saved files. Do you save your files via «Save for Web»?

Answer (score 9):

`exiftool` is also very powerful.

[Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

Answer (score 4):

### [Phatch](http://photobatch.wikidot.com/)

I mostly use Phatch. It does handle metadata but it's aimed at batch processing so it's particularly good for workflow.

```
sudo apt install phatch
```

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for, I need something similar to Exifer, exif editor for windows now dead. I can use it with Wine, but I was wondering if there was something written for linux.

Answer (score 4):

I use [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) for simple EXIF extractions but I believe it is capable of transferring EXIF information from one image file to another. I am not aware of an appropriate GUI.

Some people prefer [ExifTool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/index.html).

Comment: I use exiv2, it's similar to exiftool and it's without a gui.

Comment: Excellent! Running `jhead -te PANO_date_time.jpg PANO_date_time_edited.jpg` on a photosphere I wanted to edit transfered all necessary information to the edited file so that it can be viewed in the photosphere viewer. (http://photo-sphere.appspot.com/? can add the metadata too, but adds a default sphere shape when your image may just be a cylinder.)

Answer (score 1):

I use [exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org) to extract and fix EXIF data via the CLI, and [Digikam](http://www.digikam.org/) to edit exif data in single images visually.

Answer (score 1):

Being ExifTool the most powerful tool around (unfortunately no-gui), this could be a solution: pyExifToolGUI: https://hvdwolf.github.io/pyExifToolGUI/

You could find a convenient package for Ubuntu in this PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/ubuntu/lffl

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use jBrout for some aspects of Exif manipulation.  I've written about this here : http://www.scaine.net/site/2010/01/jbrout/

I'm not convinced that it can copy Exif from one photo to another - you're better off with Phatch for that, as mentioend by outofstep.  Can you clarify why Phatch "isn't what you're looking for"?

Comment: Typically I need an exif manipulation software to do this: I have a picture, with gimp I adjust some settings and apply a frame; on the new file I lose exif information, so I need to import them from original picture before I can upload on a photo sharing site. For me it's important to have original exif info with the uploaded pictures 'cos I need to share data about camera settings,like exposition, aperture size, iso... If Phatch can do this it's ok, but I've tried without results, maybe it's my fault.

Comment: The fundamental problem seems to be the destruction of metadata by Gimp. Perhaps you could forsake Gimp and simply use Phatch? It will certainly add a simple border...

Answer (score 0):

The mapivi app, comes with the official Debian repository. It is GUI and can edit EXIF and IPTC. Additionally it shows the tags' data format, which is difficult to know from exif and exiv2.
I use mapivi as a tool for some pictures and if I need scripts, I get from it the format to prepare the script.