# Change the exposure date of a photograph

Tags: 13.04, shotwell

I use Shotwell 0.14.1 in Ubuntu 13.04, is there a way of correcting the exposure date of a photograph either by add-ons to Shotwell or through a third party application.

I have just waited 12 hours for Shotwell to index, sort and categorise my large collection of images collected over the past 5 years. However some of the photographs have been included in dated folders that are incorrect.

In the screenshot below, the photograph of the green house was taken in Malta on the 15th February 2011 and the one on the 19th June 2013 was taken on the 18th February 2011. The rest of the images from that trip in Malta have been filed in the correct place.

[image]

Clicking on the image allows you to change the Title and the description, but not the other properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Shotwell** we can adjust the date and the time of a photo by selecting *"Photos - Adjust Date and Time..."* from the panel menu:

[image]

Tick **Modify original file** to change these values not only in the Shotwell database but also in the file.

For further editing of exif data have a look at this question:

- [Can someone recommend an Exif editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9341/can-someone-recommend-an-exif-editor)

Comment: I searched the world over for that, never thought of opening the photo and doing it... Thanks also for the link. most helpful.

Comment: You don't even have to open it - just select it in the preview window.