# adding exif data (photo taken date) to photos

Tags: photo-management, exif

I have photos without Exif data (some were scanned, some were sent by WhatsApp) - but I have them sorted on folders with other pictures that have Exif data.

Is it possible to add the minimum Exif create date (or maximum) in a folder to all the photos without this Exif data (inside the same folder)?

Comment: You should be able to use `exiv2` as described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153447/103151 to change the timestamps.

Comment: Another usable tool is `exiftool` (see http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). You could write a script to read the EXIF tags (via `exiftool`) for each file and, if not existant, set them through `exiftool`. There is also a batch mode in `exiftool`, maybe it is possible to use that.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit the properties, on a PC r-click and edit the properties. On a Mac the steps are similar.

You are aware you can't really get accurate data from original photo but can add exif data.

There are software programs that can actually do batch jobs. I believe the best way would be to sort files, put them in labelled folders: Mom, POP, Billy-Bob and use the batch function that way.

Afterwards you could make minor exif adjustments if needed and save yourself some pain-staking work.

Comment: We are on Ubuntu, here, are we? If you have Windows, you can use [GeoSetter](http://www.geosetter.de/en) for this purpose.

Comment: i understand i cant get accurate data from original photo.. i would like to extract the exif data from a file in the same folder that has exif date and add it to all the photos that don't - in the same folder

Comment: Try this link for more info. https://askubuntu.com/questions/9341/can-someone-recommend-an-exif-editor